# find all possible paths between source and destination in undirected graph in python

Tags: python, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

I have adjacency list right for undirected graph but my code is reaching its recursion limit.

```
adjacencyList = [[1, 2], [0], [0]]
visited=[]
def allpath(v1,v2,path,_output):
    if v1==v2:
        _output.append(path)
        return _output
    else:
        global visited
        if v1 not in visited:
            for nx in adjacencyList[v1]:
                if nx not in visited:
                    allpath(nx,v2,path+[nx],_output)
            visited.append(v1)
output=[]
print(allpath(0,2,[0],output))
```

Comment: You need to add your node to the `visited` list BEFORE you recurse.  You don't need `global` for this.  I don't understand what your `adjacencyList` means,  Is 1 adjacent to 2?  Then what do the lone `[0]` entries represent?

Comment: @TimRoberts adjacencyList tells about the neighbors of a node e.g node 0 has 1 & 2 as neighbors while 1 & 2 both has only one neighbor 0
In adjacencyList index no represent the node while the entries at that index represents the neighbors of that node.